# datetimepicker not opening when pressing on button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker

im trying to make a website, and I need a calendar so that the users can plan in a meeting. I tried getting a datetime picker from the internet, but when I run the page and press the button, the calendar is not opening. (im doing this in visual studio code ASP.net C#/html). I have no idea why

Here is the code:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

```js
 $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: seems working fine. (I have added your code in code snippet and it's working)

Comment: What else could be wrong? Is it maybe something with my browser? I tried both on internet explorer and google chrome but didnt work. Here in the code snippet it does work though but when i execute in the localhost with command 'dotnet run' the calendar is not opening when i click on the button

Comment: The code seems to work fine.

Comment: yes here it does but i have no idea why it does not work when i execute it in the localhost with 'dotnet run', could it be something with my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use the native date picker to avoid cross-browser issues.

Remove these lines of code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

And replace this line:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" />
```

With this line:

```
<input type='date' class="form-control" />
```

Example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='date' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```